# Programmatically compile TypeScript from tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript

I have a TypeScript project that contains a couple other file types that I need to transpile as part of the build process.  I can create an NPM script like `tsc && other-tool`, which works but once you have 3 or 4 tools setup like this the NPM script can start to become a bit complicated.  I would like to step things up a bit and create an actual build script (e.g., `build.js`).  I am not to the point where I need some heavyweight build infrastructure like gulp, just a simple .js script with a few lines.

However, I cannot figure out how to turn `tsc` at the command line (which uses a `tsconfig.json` for compilation) into a nodejs function call.  How can I call `tsc` from within a nodejs script?  I would *strongly prefer* to not just shell out to TSC CLI, as it seems crazy to me to shell out to a JS script from within a JS script instead of just calling the JS script directly.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6387

Comment: @ritaj It is unfortunate that it is that complicated, happen to have any idea to emulate the `--watch` option using that strategy?

Comment: Maybe with [spawn](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) or [exec](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback). Maybe it would be also possible to [fork](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options), and to call: `require("typescript/lib/tsc.js")` in the child process.